# remove first element in array after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data of array which look like this:

`myArray=['0','1','2','3','4','5'];`

Now I want to remove the every first element of the array after 10 seconds. 
I am not asking for the complete code right now I just want to get some tips and suggestions on how to do that. Any answers are welcome.

Comment: [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first element from an array. It also returns that element, but if you don't want it you can just ignore that.

Comment: what do you want to do with the returned values - cut out the middle man - myArray=[];, or use SetInterval()

Comment: you can use setInterval function to run after a interval and shift function to remove first element

Answer (score 5):

I understand you want it to happen every 10 seconds because you've written "every first element".

```
var timer = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (myArray.length > 0)
        myArray.splice(0, 1);
    else
        window.clearInterval(timer);
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Or an even better solution as @Cerbrus suggested, by using [Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

```
var timer = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (myArray.length > 0)
        myArray.shift();
    else
        window.clearInterval(timer);
}, 10 * 1000);
```

---

If you want it to happen only once, use `window.setTimeout` instead of `window.setInterval`:

```
var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
    myArray.shift();
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)? And why are you using an interval?

Comment: Oh, you don't have to check for `.length`. `.shift()` works on empty arrays. And as a personal preference, I'd remove the multiplication to get the timeout's ms parameter. Just use `10000`.

Comment: @Cerbrus The length check is there because of the interval. And for the multiplication - It seems that the OP may be new to JS so I just wanted it to be clear enough

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
setTimeout(function({
   var removedVariable = myArray.shift();
}), 10000)
```

Comment: Using the proper array operation, and a timeout instead of a interval. +1.

Comment: Tank you @ Cerbrus. You are right, I changed it to `10000`.

Comment: Hm, `.shift()` returns the removed element. Maybe you don't want to assign that to a new array (Or change `newArray` to `removedVariable`)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help:

http://jsfiddle.net/zho0ysgc/6/

```
 var arry = [1, 2, 3]
var count
alert(arry);

setTimeout (function(){ 
arry.shift();   
alert(arry);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` if you're immediately going to clear it any way. Use `setTimeout` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Removing first element in Array using jQuery ['shift'](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp) method, and printing in DOM [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/fgh02tyf/)

```
myArray=['0','1','2','3','4','5'];            
    setInterval(function(){      
        if(myArray.length > 0) {
            $('.print').html(myArray.shift());    
        }    
    },1000)
```